# Creating stripe customer with subscription and anchor via checkout

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using PHP in the backend (but my problem is not language dependent).

I'd like to create a stripe customer with a subscription and an anchor date for invoicing dates, and a card payment method. The anchor is giving me a headache.

I believe the general steps are: on server side I can create a customer, then a session, then in the browser code I call stripe.redirectToCheckout() where I pass in the session id. This works without the anchor, subscription and card are created ok.

However I do not know where to specify the anchor. At https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create I found no input argument for anchor date.

As the session create function has an input argument for a subscription, I have tried to create a customer, then a subscription, then a session. However creating the subscription fails with the reason that the customer does not have a paymentmethod.

If I do the working steps: create customer, session, call redirectToCheckout() then I cannot change the anchor of the subscription (except for changing it to now which is not what I want) so I need a way to create a subscription with the anchor.

Could someone please let me know what I missed?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

When creating the Checkout Session, you can pass subscription specific parameters using the [`subscription_data`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data) hash. Unfortunately the [`billing_cycle_anchor`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-billing_cycle_anchor) parameter can not be used when creating a Checkout Session.

As a workaround, you could use a [trial period](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials) as a way to fix the billing anchor to the specific date you require.

Comment: Thank you for this. Trial end is not a good solution for me as I do not want to have a trial period.
I started looking at stripe.createPaymentMethod(). Is that a possible path that could work or is it going to be a dead end?

Comment: You are pretty limited in regards to subscription flexibility when using Checkout. If you need a more complex subscription integration, then you'd need to [build this yourself](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/elements).

Comment: Thank you for the link.
I have managed to create a paymentmethod from javascript using stripe.createPaymentMethod(). I haven't tried it yet but I expect in php I can now create a customer, set its paymentmethod to the ID I get in javascript, then create a subscription, set its anchor date and maybe that is it. On the other hand I do not know how this works with SCA. I was using the SCA test card number and the bank simulation window did not pop up. Do you know if this solution is SCA compliant? If not, is there a way to make it SCA compliant? Thank you.

Comment: So I have a paymentmethod id from stripe.createPaymentMethod(), on server side I create a setup intent, back in javascript I call stripe.confirmCardSetup() with the secret of the setupintent, and the SCA simulation dialog appeared. I hope it means this is an SCA compliant solution. I'll let you know if the planned server side steps work out.

Comment: Yes the steps I described above worked; i am hoping that it is SCA compliant. Thank you for the links and suggestions you posted.

Answer (score 0):

`billing_cycle_anchor` can be set via the Checkout session since since 26 April, 2023. [See docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-billing_cycle_anchor).

Example:

```php
$stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
  'mode' => 'subscription',
  'subscription_data' => [
    'billing_cycle_anchor' => 1682985600
  ]
]);
```